# Chromebook ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED error

Tags: google-chrome, dns, chromebook

I have seen answers on similar issues for Windows, but no solution for Chromebook which is were the issue is occurring.

The error will popup every now and again and then disappear after a while and then return, there is no predicability to it and because it's Chromebook, I do not think there is any way to resolve it with command prompts.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: So tempting to down vote this...  you need to supply at least some specifics in order to help you.  Based on your statement, there could be anything causing this from a re-connecting WiFi connection to DNS servers in a SERVFAIL state for the name you're resolving.

Comment: I have a similar issue with my Chromebook. It seems to be an issue with the WiFi dropping out a lot. Still looking for a solution myself :(